# For-loops in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

What is the best way of doing this in Python?

```
for (v = n / 2 - 1; v >= 0; v--)
```

I actually tried Google first, but as far as I can see the only solution would be to use `while`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way to do it is with `xrange()`:

```
for v in xrange(n // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
```

(Or, in Python 3.x, with `range()` instead of `xrange()`.) `//` is flooring division, which makes sure the result is a whole number.

Comment: hughdbrown's version should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 15):

I would do this:

```
for i in reversed(range(n // 2)):
    # Your code
    pass
```

It's a bit clearer that this is a reverse sequence, what the lower limit is, and what the upper limit is.

Comment: @ ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: true, but this does not have the benefit you may think. range() in pre-3.0 pythons pulls all the data at once. xrange() acts like a generator, pulling only one item at a time. But if you are going to reverse a sequence, you need all the data at once, so reversed(range()) and reversed(xrange()) will work in the same way: they'll each have all the data pulled before it is reversed.

Comment: I actually ended up using this, big thanks! A follow-up question: I know I've seen it, but how do I print a `range()` (an iterator I guess)? Edit: thanks hughdbrown for the performance note, I'll consider that in more complex applications

Comment: @hughdbrown: it does have the benefit you think I might be thinking. Check the `dir(xrange)` output and note the `__reversed__` special method.

Comment: @ ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: The things I learn. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed explains that `reversed` can consume `__reversed__` method if present -- so that `xrange()` could be implemented optimally, as ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ suggests. See also: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0322/

Answer (score 5):

```
for v in range(n//2, -1, -1)
```

However, in 90% of the cases when you would have used a `for` loop in C/Java/C#/VB, what you really want is [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
listOfStuff = [doSomethingWith(v) for v in range(n//2, -1, -1)]
```

Comment: -1: This has one too many items. It incorrectly includes `n//2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for v in xrange(n/2 - 1, 0, -1):
   #your code here
```

Where v and n are `int`s or treated as `int`s. This means that the division will be an integer division, i.e., `1/2 == 0 is True`.

Note: This is for Python 2.x .

Comment: -1: This has one too few items. It incorrectly omits `0`. Separately, in python3 it fails because `n/2` generates a float (`TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`). But maybe that's why you called out that it is for python 2.x.