# Python for loop equavalent to C

Tags: python

I'm new to python and i can't figure out how to write a reverse for loop in python.

e.g. the `python` equivalent to the `C` lang loop

```
for (i = 10; i >= 0; --i) {
    printf ("%d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625540/for-loops-in-python/2625846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python [range](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) method.

for loop in `python` equavalent to `C` will be:

```
for i in range(10, -1, -1):
    print i
```

Answer (score 11):

```
for i in range(10, -1, -1):
    print i
```

You rarely need indexed loops in Python though.

Usually you're iterating over some sequence:

```
for element in sequence:
   do_stuff(element)
```

To do this in reverse:

```
for element in reversed(sequence):
   do_stuff(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this    `for i in range(10,-1,-1)`

Answer (score 0):

As Pavel mentions, you rarely need indexed loops. For those occasions you do, though, there's `enumerate`:

```
for i, element in enumerate(sequence):
    print '%s is in index %d' % (element, i)
```